# direct answer to sparql select query of equivalent class for graphdb?

Tags: select, sparql, graphdb

I have an "EquivalentTo" definition in Protege of a class *EquivClass* as *(hasObjProp some ClassA) and (has_data_prop exactly 1 rdfs:Literal)*

Is there a form of SPARQL query for GraphDB 9.4 to get the "direct" answer to a select query of an equivalent class without having to collect and traverse all the constituent blank nodes explicitly? Basically, I'm looking for a short cut. I'm not looking to get instances of the equivalent class, just the class definition itself in one go. I've tried to search for answers, but I'm not really clear on what possibly related answers are saying.

I'd like to get something akin to

*(hasObjProp some ClassA) and (has_data_prop exactly 1 rdfs:Literal)*

as an answer to the SELECT query on *EquivClass*. If the answer is "not possible", that's enough. I can write the blank node traversal with the necessary properties myself.

Thanks!!

Files are -

`Ontology imported into GraphDB: tester.owl` - https://pastebin.com/92K7dKRZ

`SELECT of all triples from GraphDB *excluding* inferred triples: tester-graphdb-sparql-select-all-excl-inferred.tsv` - https://pastebin.com/fYdG37v5

`SELECT of all triples from GraphDB *including* inferred triples: tester-graphdb-sparql-select-all-incl-inferred.tsv` - https://pastebin.com/vvqPH1FZ

Added sample query in response to @UninformedUser. I use "select *" for example, but really I'm interested in the "end results", ie, ?fp, ?fo, ?rop, ?roo. Essentially, I'm looking for something simpler and more succinct than what I have below.The example I posted only has a single intersection ("and" clause). In my real world set, there are multiple equiv classes with different numbers of "and" clauses.

```
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX : <http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2020/9/tester#>
select * where { 
    :EquivClass owl:equivalentClass ?bneq .
    ?bneq ?p ?bnhead .
    ?bnhead rdf:first ?first .
    ?first ?fp ?fo .
    ?bn3 rdf:rest ?rest .
    ?rest ?rp ?ro .
    ?ro ?rop ?roo .
    filter(?bn3 != owl:Class && ?ro!=rdf:nil)
}
```

Comment: which reasoning profile do you use? I mean, if you use OWL 2 RL for example, you class expression as the superclass part of an EquivalentClasses axiom is **not** covered, see the specs: https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-profiles/#Reasoning_in_OWL_2_RL_and_RDF_Graphs_using_Rules - like cardinality restrictions other than `max` are not supported anyways, and you use `exactly`

Comment: what I also don't understand is why you would need "blank node traversal" - what does this mean? For querying instance data you don't need this, this would only hold for querying the schema. Or am I missing something? You will also need `group by` and `cnt` for the cardinality restriction by the way

Comment: I'm not querying instance data for this class - I want the class definition components without the intervening blank nodes.

Comment: ah, I see. You want the class expression or better said all triples making up the class expression? What kind of query would this be? I mean, it would have to be a `CONSTRUCT` query and even then I don't understand how this should look like in SPARQL. I mean, doing just `select ?ce where {:A owl:equivalentTo ?ce}` would be odd or at least I cannot imagine what the binding of `?ce` would look like. Same for `CONSTRUCT` queries which is what you want I guess? You want the triples, right?

Comment: that makes my wondering - how do you do the blank node traversal? Can you give an example query maybe?

Comment: "... all triples making up the class expression" - exactly. I know I can't query for blank nodes directly, so a query might be something like what  I've added to the original post above, but more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

You can unroll the list using a property path:

```
prefix :      <http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2020/9/tester#> 
prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> 
prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
prefix xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 
prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 

select * {
  :EquivClass owl:equivalentClass/owl:intersectionOf/rdf:rest*/rdf:first ?restr.
  ?restr a owl:Restriction .
  optional {?restr owl:onProperty     ?prop}
  optional {?restr owl:cardinality    ?cardinality}
  optional {?restr owl:someValuesFrom ?class}
}
```

This returns:

```
|   | restr   | prop           | cardinality                  | class   |
| 1 | _:node3 | :hasObjProp    |                              | :ClassA |
| 2 | _:node5 | :has_data_prop | "1" ^^xsd:nonNegativeInteger |         |
```